# Explain Android Studio console output format and how configure to show date/time in each line?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and it would be really nice to know *when* a line of trace was emitted.

A simple print statement in a Flutter class like this:

```
print("hello, console logging");
```

outputs this in the Console / "4. Run" bottom-tab:

```
I/flutter ( 6731): hello, console logging
```

Three questions:

1. What does "I/flutter" mean?
2. What does "6731" mean?
3. Is it possible to configure something to add a timestamp to each line to show "HH:MM?"

I've researched this for about an hour and I can't find any answers.

Answer (score 2):

`I/flutter:` It means message logging of '***Information***' kind. `flutter` is the tag for the log. More info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log

In the android studio, you can find the method `Log.i()` which accepts a TAG and a message to log. Example. `Log.i("flutter", "Some message here..");`

To print the time of the log you can append `TimeOfDay.now().toString()` with your print message, as `print("hello, console logging. Time: " + TimeOfDay.now().toString());`

Comment: Thank you.  I've never heard of a logging system that doesn't auto prepend the time.